# Using python code to scubb a website

Tags: python, filter, html

I would like to scrubb the following page `http://209.105.250.69:8382/` to get the number of listeners using Python

```
<td>Current Listeners:</td>
<td class="streamdata">28</td>
```

and here is the code from the website

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Icecast Streaming Media Server</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body topmargin="0" leftmargin="0" rightmargin="0" bottommargin="0">
<h2>Icecast2 Status</h2>
<br><div class="roundcont">
<div class="roundtop"><img src="/corner_topleft.jpg" class="corner" style="display: none"></div>
<table border="0" width="100%" id="table1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4"><tr><td bgcolor="#656565">
<a class="nav" href="admin/">Administration</a><a class="nav" href="status.xsl">Server Status</a><a class="nav" href="server_version.xsl">Version</a>
</td></tr></table>
<div class="roundbottom"><img src="/corner_bottomleft.jpg" class="corner" style="display: none"></div>
</div>
<br><br><div class="roundcont">
<div class="roundtop"><img src="/corner_topleft.jpg" class="corner" style="display: none"></div>
<div class="newscontent">
<div class="streamheader"><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<colgroup align="left"></colgroup>
<colgroup align="right" width="300"></colgroup>
<tr>
<td><h3>Mount Point /listen.mp3</h3></td>
<td align="right">
<a href="/listen.mp3.m3u">M3U</a><a href="/listen.mp3.xspf">XSPF</a>
</td>
</tr>
</table></div>
<table border="0" cellpadding="4">
<tr>
<td>Stream Title:</td>
<td class="streamdata">Quran Kareem Radio</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Stream Description:</td>
<td class="streamdata">Quran Kareem Radio</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Content Type:</td>
<td class="streamdata">audio/mpeg</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Mount started:</td>
<td class="streamdata">Wed, 17 Jul 2013 05:40:46 -0400</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Bitrate:</td>
<td class="streamdata">60</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Current Listeners:</td>
<td class="streamdata">28</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Peak Listeners:</td>
<td class="streamdata">202</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Stream Genre:</td>
<td class="streamdata">Islam</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Stream URL:</td>
<td class="streamdata"><a target="_blank" href="http://qkradio.com.au">http://qkradio.com.au</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Current Song:</td>
<td class="streamdata"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
<div class="roundbottom"><img src="/corner_bottomleft.jpg" class="corner" style="display: none"></div>
</div>
<br><br>&nbsp;


<div class="poster">Support icecast development at <a class="nav" target="_blank" href="http://www.icecast.org">www.icecast.org</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So what have you tried?

Comment: cuurently working on BeautifulSoup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(s)
>>> td1 = soup.find('td', text='Current Listeners:')
>>> td2 = td1.find_next_sibling('td')
>>> td2.text
'28'
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to use a HTML parser like [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/). I'm not going to post a full solution (because it looks like you haven't attempted to do anything), but here's a demo:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
html = the_above
soup = BS(html)
print soup.find_all('tr')
```

This prints every `<tr>` tag in the code (as a list)